# Catch TimeoutException (Synchronous) for flutter_blue connect method

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I connect to a Bluetooth device using the [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) plugin with a timeout.

I am calling `connect()` as follows:

```dart
  try {
    await device.connect(timeout: Duration(seconds:4);
  } on TimeoutException catch(e) {
    print("error");
  }
```

The `timeout` exception is never caught, and the connect method **hangs indefinitely**.

If I inspect the code for the `connect()` method, I see that the `TimeoutException` is thrown inside a function passed to a timer.

> Is the connect() running in a different zone?

```dart
Future<void> connect({
  Duration timeout,
  bool autoConnect = true,
}) async {
  var request = protos.ConnectRequest.create()
                  ..remoteId = id.toString()
                  ..androidAutoConnect = autoConnect;
  
  Timer timer;
  if (timeout != null) {
    timer = Timer(timeout, () {
      disconnect();
      throw TimeoutException('Failed to connect in time.', timeout);
    });
  }
    
  await FlutterBlue.instance._channel
    .invokeMethod('connect', request.writeToBuffer());
  await state.firstWhere((s) => s == BluetoothDeviceState.connected);  
  timer?.cancel();
    
  return;
}
```

Based on the connect() method implementation,

> Is it impossible for me to await a connect call and synchronously determine a timeout has occurred?

It seems like the connect method implementation is totally unintuitive, but I can not be sure.